# Windows 10, xcopy failing

Tags: windows-10, xcopy

I have a python script that transfers a file structure, in the python script it uses a for loop to iterate through files and folders, below is a typical example of the instruction it tries to execute:

```
$ xcopy ../../Core/Service\ Groups/Core_Build/Windows\ 10\ x86\ (1) ../../Core/Releases/Windows\ 10\ x86\ (1)/Windows\ 10\ x86\ (1a) /f /e /y
```

This is executed in a bash script and results in:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I cannot see anything wrong with the command, all spaces have been escaped, I removed quotes around the paths as that causes a different error.

The source path does exist and I've verified the relative reference is correct in both cases.

If I try:

```
$ xcopy /f /e /y "../../Core/Service Groups/Core_Build/Windows 10 x86 (1)" "../../Core/Releases/Windows 10 x86 (1)/Windows 10 x86 (1a)/"
```

I get:

```
Invalid number of parameters
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some weird characters or locale settings, which may mess everything up? When I try your last command, the command is accepted (no `Invalid number of arguments` error message).

Comment: Have you tried doing this in a batch file or cmd?

Comment: @NekoMusume, yes, same results.

Comment: Have you tried using the backslashe for the file path?

Comment: @NekoMusume, yes, escaping with \\, same results.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must put path in quotes if it contains spaces and other special chars.
2. Put your source and destination to beginning of command:

```
xcopy "../../Core/Service Groups/Core_Build/Windows 10 x86 (1)" "../../Core/Releases/Windows 10 x86 (1)/Windows 10 x86 (1a)/" /fey
```

Comment: Thank you, did you see the 2nd attempt whcih is in quotes ?

Comment: Signature is `Xcopy <Source> [<Destination>] [<Options>]`